# IBM Websphere on kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, websphere, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to load IBM Websphere on kubernetes pod using Helm charts, here is my template

**Deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.wasnd.name }}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.wasnd.name }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.wasnd.replicas }}
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 0
      maxUnavailable: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.wasnd.name }}
        alert_severity: critical
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values: 
                - {{ .Values.wasnd.name }}
            topologyKey: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.wasnd.name }}
        image: {{ .Values.deploy.containerImage.wasnd.image }}
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.imagePullPolicy }}
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: {{ .Values.wasnd.limits.memory }}
          requests:
            memory: {{ .Values.wasnd.requests.memory }}
        stdin: true
        tty: true
        command: [/sst/bin/bootstrap.sh]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.wasnd.name }}
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: {{ .Values.wasnd.name }}
  ports:
    - name: "https"
      port: 9043
      targetPort: 9043
      protocol: TCP
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - name: "9060"
      port: 9060
      targetPort: 9060
  selector:
    app: {{ .Values.wasnd.name }}
```

I have allocated 1Gi of memory for both requests and limits

The deployment image contains all the scripts and they execute, but upon completion of the script I keep getting this error

ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv01 profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: lfe1
ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.
ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization. Server logs,
startServer.log, and other log files under

This works fine on my docker container

Comment: Do you see any errors in startServer.log, e.g. **/logs/server1/startServer.log**?   I'm not saying it'll necessarily help, but note if you're more familiar with the basic logging format you can run with env var:  `ENABLE_BASIC_LOGGING=true`  to see the logs in a plain text format.

Comment: Managed to fix it by increasing the memory for both requests and limits to 5Gi.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by increasing memory

```
  requests:
    memory: "5Gi"
  limits:
    memory: "5Gi"
```